# Kubernetes cannot access app via POD IP

Tags: kubernetes

I set up a cluster with 2 machines, which are not in the same local subnet but they can connect each other, machine A is Master + Node and machine B is Node. Then I use `flannel` (subnet `172.16.0.0/16`) as the network plugin. After deployed apps, I encountered a problem that I can access the app via POD IP on machine A, but I cannot access the same app on machine B via POD IP, and curl command would say `No route to the host`172.16.0.x`. 
I think there is no route rules to other machine, but I don't know how to configure the network. Could anyone help to explain if I miss something important? Thank you very much.

I use this [kubernetes/contrib](https://github.com/kubernetes/contrib/tree/master/ansible/roles/flannel) ansible script to deploy cluster, and did not change any configuration about flannel.

Comment: Please share with us your flannel config.

Comment: @Akar Hi, I update my question description.

Comment: I think at first you should try to use the new version of Flannel. In defaults/main.yaml set flannel_version: 0.10.0

Answer (score 0):

You can use the type:NodePort to access the pod over all of the node's IPs